# Virtual sequence class plan

Tags: uvm

I am writing some code for a virtual sequence as follows:

```
class base_v_seq extends uvm_sequence #(uvm_sequence_item);
seqr1 seqr1h;
seqr2 seqr2h;
//function new......
endclass

class v_seq1 extends base_v_seq #(uvm_sequence_item);
//...
task body();
seq1 seq1h;
seq2 seq2h;
seq1h=seq1::type_id::create("seq1");

start_item(seq1.w_transh);--------------(1)
assert(se1.w_trans.randomize);
finish_item(seq1.w_transh);

seq1.start(seqr1);
endclass

class test extends uvm_test();
//...
task run_phase();
v_seq1.start(null);
endtask
endclass

class seq1 extends uvm_sequence#(uvm_sequence_item);
//...
wr_trans wr_transh;

endclass
```

my doubt is that when I am starting `v_seq1` in `test` it will call the `task body` method which it contains `start_item()` the `seq1` is also having `start_item()`; does the `start_item` present in physical sequence create any problems? how does the data transfer happen between `v_seq1` and `seq1`?
and my another question is, is "seq1.start(seqr1);" required?

Answer (score 0):

Seq_1 creates an item and sends it directly to the sequencer on which it runs. The sequencer will check whether an item exists when the driver calls seq_item_port.get(), if yes, the sequencer will return the item. So no data transfers between seq_1 and vseq. Just remember that the virtual sequnce is used to coordinate the physical sequences

Comment: And for your last question, I think you may not call start start_item(seq1.w_transh), this violates the encapsultion of class. You should just call seq1.start(seqr1), and do start_item in seq1's body.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is something ordering issue in your code. You should first start the sequnece on a sequencer so by default the bodu method of that sequence will be called, where you will have `start_item` method on packet for transaction purpose.

Your virtual sequence can look like this.

```
class vseq extends uvm_sequence #(uvm_sequnce_item);
  // Handles of the Sequencers
  a_sequencer_t a_sequencer;
  b_sequencer_t b_sequencer;

  seq1 aseq;
  seq2 bseq;

  task body();
  begin
    aseq = seq1::type_id::create("aseq");
    bseq = seq2::type_id::create("bseq");

    // Start interface specific sequences on the appropriate target sequencers:
    aseq.start(a_sequencer);
    bseq.start(b_sequencer);
  end
endclass

// In the testbench,
vseq v1 = vseq::type_id::create("vseq");
v1.a_sequencer = <a_sequencer_t handle>;
v1.b_sequencer = <b_sequencer_t handle>;

v1.start(null);
```

Please refer [UVM Cookbook](https://verificationacademy.com/cookbook/uvm) for detailed explanation and example.